# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

I've got simple `python` functions.

```
def readMainTemplate(templateFile):
    template = open(templateFile, 'r')
    data = template.read()
    index1 = data.index['['] #originally I passed it into data[]
    index2 = data.index[']']
    template.close()
    return data[index1:index2]

def writeMainTemplate(template, name):
    file = open(name, 'w')
    file.write(template)
    file.close()

#runMainTemplate('main.template')
def runMainTemplate(template):
    code = readMainTemplate(template)
    writeMainTemplate(code, 'main.cpp')
```

They basically suppose to read from file some kind of template(something like this)

```
--template "main"
[
        #include <iostream>

        using namespace std;

        int main()
        {
            return 0;
        }
]
```

and then write it to file(basically generating `main.cpp` template)

I run it from command line using this command

```
python -c "from genmain import runMainTemplate; runMainTemplate('main.template')"
```

but I've got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "genmain.py", line 18, in runMainTemplate
    code = readMainTemplate(template)
  File "genmain.py", line 6, in readMainTemplate
    index1 = data.index['['] #originally I passed it into data[]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I thought that `data = template.read()` supposed to return `string` and string should allow to perform operation slicing `[:]`.

**But why there is an error?**

*Also a question*: **where I should put `python` scripts in order to run it anywhere in filesystem?(I want to generate file anywhere in the filesystem in the current folder by providing path to the template)**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that `index` is a method and needs to be called with `()` not `[]`. To use Kasra's example:

```
>>> s="aeer"
>>> s.index('a')
0
```

Comment: oh , very foolish mistake , i miss () ! :)