# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'is_unique'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, attributeerror

I have the following data frame:

**df1**

```
            NumOfTransactions  ComissionDeduction
2011-01-10                  2               19.90
2011-01-13                  2               19.90
2011-01-26                  1                9.95
```

**df2**

['2011-01-10']

I need to join the two so I remain with  the row in df1 for when that date is also in df2.

```
 NumOfTransactions  ComissionDeduction
    2011-01-10                  2               19.90
```

I'm trying to achieve that functionality using:

```
impact = trades.index[trades.zero == total_columns].astype(str).tolist()
trades_impact = transactions.join(impact)
```

However, I'm receiving the following error;*AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'is_unique'*

Comment: In your case, use `transactions.loc[impact]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df2` seems like a list of dates, you could then just use `loc` to index the rows based on the `DateTimeIndex` of `df1.

```
r = transactions.loc[impact] 
print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (parens instead of square brackets for `index`):

```
impact = trades.index(trades.zero == total_columns).astype(str).tolist()
trades_impact = transactions.join(impact)
```

Comment: FFR, try putting your error in google. It gave me stack overflow questions anyway and I got it in the third result with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27703120/5555637.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. I will keep that in mind for a future occasion.